# C# using indexers

Tags: c#

I have a class something like this (This is a subset of the code)

```
public struct overlay
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Byte[] b;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32[] i;
}



 class MyClass
    {
    private overlay data;    \\Initialised using data.b=new Byte[4096]

    public Int32 site0 { set { data.i[0] = value; } get { return data.i[0]; } }
    public Int32 site1 { set { data.i[1] = value; } get { return data.i[1]; } }
    public String s
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data.b, 8, 16).TrimEnd(' '); }
        set { System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value.PadRight(16)).CopyTo(data.b, 8); }
    }
    public Int32 site2 { set { data.i[5] = value; } get { return data.i[5]; } }

    }
```

I currently access the site variables like this...

```
MyClass m=new MyClass();
m.site0=1;
m.site1=1;
m.site2=1;
```

I would like to access them like this..

```
MyClass m=new MyClass();
for (Int32 i=0; i<m.sites.Count; ++i)
    m.sites[i]=1;
```

Can anyone suggest how I would do that?

Comment: Declare an array or a list of type int and access the sites by index?...

Comment: You realize that you broke the type system in a totally unsupported, unsafe way? You force a byte[] to be treated as an int[] and the result is 100% undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create indexer for field in your class. You must make your own class which will store the data and then you can make field of it's type.

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyIndexerClass Sites;
    public class MyIndexerClass
    {
        private byte[] data;

        public MyIndexerClass()
        {
            this.data = new byte[0];
        }
        public MyIndexerClass(byte[] Data)
        {
            this.data = Data;
        }

        public byte this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return data[index];
            }
            set
            {
                data[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Sites = new MyIndexerClass();
    }
    public MyClass(byte[] data)
    {
        this.Sites = new MyIndexerClass(data);
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Count` property and `foreach` on `MyIndexerClass`, you should implement [IEnumerable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022) and create your own `Enumerator`.

Comment: The problem with this is that 'Byte[] data' is part of MyIndexerClass. I need it to be part of MyClass as it contains data other than just the integers.

Comment: Yes, I did work that one out but as you can seee from the updated code the 'Byte[] data' needs to be in MyClass not the NyIndexerClass.

Comment: But why do you need that? You can access `data` through `MyClass.Sites`. If you need to load your data to byte array, you can make the `data` array public, or you can create specific methods for access. I can give further help, but you must tell me for what do you need to have `data` in `MyClass`.

Comment: The problem is that MyClass holds the Byte[] and from there I need to return multiple Int32[], some Strings, some Byte and some DateTime fields.  I could put a child indexer  class in MyClass but I can't see how to pass a reference to the Byte[].  The updatedcode in the original post shows just a Int32[] and a String but there's more in reality.

Comment: I could make it unsafe code and pass a pointer to the Byte[] but I'm trying not to go that way.

Comment: And what about hold the byte array pointer in MyClass and also in MyIndexerClass? This will solute all. In fact, it's only 4 bytes+ so it doesn't matter. Your passing byte array through MyClass, right? All what you need is to use only one of pointers and work with array.

Answer (score 0):

The [indexer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# allows to do that and it would look something like this:

```
public byte this[int index] {
 get { return data[index]; }
 set { data[index] = value; }
}
```

This defines an indexer on the type. Usage is like

```
m[i] = 1;
```

However, many array and list constructs in .NET already have indexers so you could define a field/property `sites` e.g. of Type `List<byte>`.

Comment: That would mean his client code would look like `m[i]=1` instead of `m.sites[i]=1`, though.